# Get the RNG seed of CURAND in Julia

Tags: julia

When working with Neural Networks in Julia on NVidia GPUs, if I want my trained model to be exactly replicate-able, I can use the following functions with a specific seed in each:

- `Random.seed!(x)`
- `CURAND.seed!(y)`

If I want to retrieve the seed for the first, I can simply print `Random.GLOBAL_SEED`.
I want to be able to retrieve the seed that Julia provides to CURAND for its operations on the GPU. If that's not the case at all of how the Julia CURAND interface works internally, it would be nice to at least know how it works.